# IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'path.to.my.properties' in value "${path.to.my.properties}"

Tags: java, junit, properties

I'm having this error when running "mvn test" in my spring boot application.

If instead I run the app normally with spring run configuration there's no error and is able to resolve the path.

Basically path.to.my.properties points to a file out of my intellijIdea module containing some raw data that I need to process

What could I do to avoid this error? Maybe mock that value somehow in the test?

src/main/resources/config-local.properties :

```
    path.to.my.properties=C:/Dev/ExternalFolder/route.properties
```

src\main\java\com\myapp\configuration\PropertiesConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:${path.to.my.properties}")
public class PropertiesConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public String getValueByKey(String keyValue) {
        return env.getProperty(keyValue);
    }
}
```

\src\test\java\com\test\myapp\main\TestSearchMessagesAPI.java

```
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = {Application.class})
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class TestSearchMessagesAPI {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(
            TestSearchMessagesAPI.class);


    @Value("${HTTPS_PORT}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${server.servlet.context-path}")
    private String servletPath;

    @Value("${junit.service-path-verify}")
    private String servicePathVerify;

    @BeforeAll
    public void init() {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.forEach((k, v) -> LOGGER.debug("Prop: {} - {}", k, v));
    }

    @Test
    public void testServiceVerify() {
        final ResponseEntity<String> response = assertDoesNotThrow(
                () -> executeRequest("testServiceVerify",
                        createUrl(this.servicePathVerify, null, null),
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        createHttpHeaders(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)));

        assertEquals(
                HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode(),
                "Expected Response status OK, statusCode "
                        + response.getStatusCode());
        assertTrue(doesContainKeywords(response.getBody(), "Verification ok "));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add in the test :

```
@TestPropertySource(
    locations = "classpath:config-local.properties")
```